# Двойное условие для выборки из Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, where

Есть таблица MySQL 'table' с множеством записей, пусть их 100.

Необходимо отобрать 20 последних записей WHERE row1 = '1' && row2 = '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
И включить в число выборки из всей таблицы записи (в качестве приоритетных записей), где row3 = '1' даже если они не из последней 20-ки, но чтобы суммарно получилось 20?

Как это реализовать одним запросом без дополнительных обработок из двух выборок?

Спасибо!

Comment: Я ничего не понял

Comment: ```and \ or``` + верная расстановка скобочек + правильное расположение условий в ```order by``` (там через запятую перечисление идет в порядке уменьшения важности)

Comment: А как это может выглядеть?
Попробую иначе сформулировать...

Нужно выбрать записи с row1='1' && row3='1' и дополнить их записями из последних добавленных до общего количества 20, где row1='1' && row2='1'.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось!

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE (row1 = '1' && row2 = '1') || (row1 = '1' && row3 = '1')
ORDER BY row3 DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Спасибо!